# How to load RxJS (and zone.js / reflect-metadata) with Angular 2 (beta and newer)?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, systemjs

As of Angular 2 Alpha 54 ([changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha54-2015-12-15)), `RxJS` is no longer included in Angular 2.

**Update: Turns out that `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` are also excluded.**

As a result, I now get the following errors (as seen in the Chrome dev console):

```
system.src.js:4681 GET http://localhost:3000/rxjs/Subject 404 (Not Found)F @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681
system.src.js:4681 GET http://localhost:3000/rxjs/observable/fromPromise 404 (Not Found)F @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/rxjs/Subject(…)t @ system.src.js:4681g @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681
system.src.js:4681 GET http://localhost:3000/rxjs/operator/toPromise 404 (Not Found)F @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4681
system.src.js:4681 GET http://localhost:3000/rxjs/Observable 404 (Not Found)
```

I have `RxJS` in my package.json file (^5.0.0-beta.0), and it has been installed with `npm`, but the issue is I just am not familiar enough with `SystemJS` at this time to get things running.  Here's the body section from my `index.html` file:

```
<body>
<app></app> <!-- my main Angular2 tag, which is defined in app/app as referenced below -->

<script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
    });
    System.import('./app/app');
</script>

<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have been playing around with other configurations, but none have gotten me all the way there.  My guess is that this is relatively simple, it's just my lack of understanding or the way the tools get used that is stopping me.

Here's my app.ts file that is the `app/app` referred to in the SystemJS config:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {COMMON_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [],
    template: `<div>{{greeting}}, world!</div>`
})
export class App {
    greeting:string = 'Hello';
}

bootstrap(App, [COMMON_DIRECTIVES]);
```

I'm serving the app with a livereload `Express` server that uses static mappings so that calls like `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js` are able to get the needed file even though `index.html` is served from `/src` as the root of the server and `node_modules` is actually at the same level as `src` and not inside it.

Any help would, as always, be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was fixed easily by changing the SystemJS config to the following in my `index.html` file:

```
System.config({
    map: {
        rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs' // added this map section
    },
    packages: {
        'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'} // and added this to packages
    }
});
System.import('app/app');
```

I had actually tried that, but what I failed to realize was that `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` were also no longer included in Angular 2, and I was running into that problem as well.

For those interested, I got around the lack of `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` most easily by including the `angular2-polyfills.js` file in my index.html:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
```

Now my app works just as it did with Alpha 53.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just noticed that the correct polyfills link is `<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: Note that if you're using the bundles, there is a similar Rx.js bundle in the node_modules/rxjs/bundles directory that avoids having to do any configuration.