# RxJS root directory Not Found by SystemJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, rxjs, systemjs

SystemJS appears to load rxjs modules without an issue but throws a 404 Not Found on the rxjs directory itself. All modules are the latest version and this only appears to be an issue on Windows, it works on osx.

**GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/rxjs/ 404 (Not Found)**

**Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)**
XHR finished loading: GET " localhost:8080/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js".

XHR finished loading: GET "localhost:8080/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js".

[Module loads & Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNgDa.png)

```html
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',

            },
            'components':{ format: 'register' },
            'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        },
        map: {'app': '/components',
            'rxjs': '../node_modules/rxjs',
            },


    });
    System.import('components/notes.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

```
+-- angular2@2.0.0-beta.9
+-- bootstrap@3.3.6
+-- es6-promise@3.0.2
+-- es6-shim@0.33.3
+-- jquery@2.2.1
+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
+-- systemjs@0.19.24
| +-- es6-module-loader@0.17.11
| `-- when@3.7.7
+-- typescript@1.8.7
`-- zone.js@0.5.15
  `-- es6-promise@3.1.2
```

I fixed this, it seems the way I was importing rxjs in my .ts was deprecated:

changed from

`import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';`

to:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';`

Comment: strange thing, but there are a lot of advices how to use rxjs library, but this is the only one that works! you really shoud use `from 'rxjs/Observable'` instead of `from 'rxjs'`

Comment: Just... wow... JS should be prohibited by law!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too think that you're not needed to add rxjs in your System.config. It'll automatically take care of it. Like mentiond here in [A2 5min Quick Start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) you just have to add `<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>` to your index.html and point your SystemJS to your main component , rest it'll take care the rest.

Comment: added amended import statement for rxjs which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add `rxjs` special things in your system config. SystemJs supports `node_modules` module lookups by default.

Comment: I have it <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>, but without it I get [more] load errors for the rxjs components as well as the error mentioned above. so added it as per this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318885/how-to-load-rxjs-and-zone-js-reflect-metadata-with-angular-2-beta-and-newer.