# Angular 2 Beta 9 not finding RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I've been trying multiple times to get a basic service built using Subject and BehaviorSubject from RXJS... My issue is that every time I include RXJS the TypeScript compiles with no errors but I get this error:

[image: Console Screen Grab]

After updating my index.html based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318885/how-to-load-rxjs-and-zone-js-reflect-metadata-with-angular-2-beta-and-newer) post I get the following errors (and no page load).

[image: Post Updated html file]

I'm still pretty new to Angular 2, Typescript, and RXJS so any help is appreciated. I've posted what I believe to be all relevant code below, let me know if there is something else that might assist and i'll update with requested part.

Index.html * Updated

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>SCV Equipment Tracker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- Front End Libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/css/main.css"/>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            paths: {
                // DON'T CHANGE KEY OF THIS PATH, CHANGE VALUE ONLY
                // IF YOU EXPOSE node_modules as public / static dir to your app, you can remove this line.
                'semantic-ui/dist/components/*': 'semantic/dist/components/*.js',
                // REQUIRED BY ANGULAR 2 ( CHANGE PATH )
            },
            map: {
                // IF YOU ARE NOT ABLE TO LOAD FROM node_modules
                // you must copy ng-semantic from /node_modules/ng-semantic
                // ( files: semantic.js, semantic.d.ts and folder: ng-semantic )
                // and set path to it
                'ng-semantic/semantic': 'node_modules/ng-semantic/semantic.js'
            },
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<eqTracker>
    <div class="ui active inverted dimmer">
        <div class="ui large text loader">Loading</div>
    </div>
</eqTracker>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
{
  "name": "equipment-tracker-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "front end for equipment tracker",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run tsc:w ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.0.17",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.1.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

UserService.ts (note this is a clone of ng-book 2 user service as that's what i'm learning angular 2 from)

```js
import {Injectable, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

//Models
import {User} from "../models/user.model";

@Injectable()
export class UserService{
    currentUser: Subject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

    public setCurrentUser(newUser: User):void{
        this.currentUser.next(newUser);
    }
}

export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
    bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)
];
```

Updated error based on Thierry Templier's response
So after updating my index.html page based on Thierry's answer I get the following:
[image: Post errors after updated index.html]

Now i'm missing all my angular stuff too...

Edit With Temporary Solution:
So I found a solution that worked thanks to Thierry Templier's comment... From the original service I needed to include the rx stuff like import `{Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';`
After that with the mappings I already had It did work

```
System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        paths: {
            // DON'T CHANGE KEY OF THIS PATH, CHANGE VALUE ONLY
            // IF YOU EXPOSE node_modules as public / static dir to your app, you can remove this line.
            'semantic-ui/dist/components/*': 'semantic/dist/components/*.js',
            // REQUIRED BY ANGULAR 2 ( CHANGE PATH )
        },
        map: {
            // IF YOU ARE NOT ABLE TO LOAD FROM node_modules
            // you must copy ng-semantic from /node_modules/ng-semantic
            // ( files: semantic.js, semantic.d.ts and folder: ng-semantic )
            // and set path to it
            'ng-semantic/semantic': 'node_modules/ng-semantic/semantic.js',
            'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2',
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
```

From everything I've read trying to solve this issue, and trying to learn Angular 2 Thierry Templier should be right and the mappings should not be needed. I'll try to dive in and solve that issue some other time, but that and it was his comment that helped me get a working angular back is why his answer was accepted.

Comment: I think I got this error when I had wrong rxjs verision, not the one which was required by angular2...

Comment: @eesdil What version of rxjs were you using? Per the most recent quick start Angular2 beta 9 uses RXJS 5.0.0-beta2 I deleted and forced a re-install and still had the error, are the docs wrong?

Comment: It should be fine. I am using jspm usually, so this is different thing. Also I can see that you have wrong paths...  Thierry should be right, shouldnt include the rxjs in the map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you include the `node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js` file, I don't think that you need to configure rxjs into your SystemJS configuration.

As a matter of fact, the file registers explicitly modules using `System.register`. Same for Angular2 files.

I would update your configuration like this:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  paths: {
    'semantic-ui/dist/components/*': 'semantic/dist/components/*.js'
  },
  map: {
    'ng-semantic/semantic': 'node_modules/ng-semantic/semantic.js',
  },
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Thierry Templier, thanks for the suggestion, that is the same configuration that generated the first set of errors... (if i remove the 'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2' line I can't get routers or anything else either). So still not a fix.

Comment: In fact, to use routing in Angular2, you need to include the `node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js` file in your HTML file...

Comment: Sorry it was the `router.dev.js` file in my previous comment ;-)

Comment: Still no change with or without that file added it still doesn't work, without node_modules/angular 2 the browser looks for angular 2 inside the root directory (not node_modules) and removing the register rxjs map and the broswer looks for all rxjs files in root directory as well...

Comment: Really strange! Because I use it like that ;-) What is the exact error?

Comment: Thanks again Thierry ... Updated question with new error log and index.html

Comment: Regarding rxjs you should import this way: import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: Otherwise do you have the following in the angular.dev.js file: System.register('angular2/platform/browser', ... ? Is the angular2.dev.js file correctly loaded?

Comment: Thanks Thierry, the import from rxjs/Rx was the fix I needed to get my code up... I still needed the mappings though (no idea why and all tutorials and things i've read say i shouldn't...). The files are all correctly loading and i've done no modifications to the npm angular 2 beta 9 download. But as that is a different issue i'll tackle that later and if needed open another question.

Comment: The pre-last comment by Thierry Templier saved the day!